# Is there an unique identifier for MS outlook email message?

Tags: api, rest, email, outlook, ms-office

I know that MS set a field called ConversationId that uniquely identify a mail thread for each user. This works for replies of non domain users inclusive.

So, how MS does this? Are they using an hidden unique email ID for that?

I'd like know if there some way to identify messages generated by MS outlook users (web) that could be used to track a message among the domain users.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583.aspx. All of these properties can be accessed using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.